# Why is /tmp not written to /var

Tags: disk-space-utilization, diskmanagement, server-setup

My CentOS 6.5 server has the following setup;

```
$ df -h
Filesystem              Size  Used  Avail Use%  Mounted on
/dev/dv1                8.0G  713M  6.7G  10%   /
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr    9.9G  2.5G  6.9G  27%   /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-var    248G  138G  97G   59%   /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-home   99G   928M  93G   1%    /home
```

When the `fstab` has the following;

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
/dev/dv1        /               ext3    defaults,noatime        1 1
/dev/sda2       none            swap    sw
/dev/sdb2       none            swap    sw
/dev/vg00/usr   /usr            ext4    defaults,noatime        0 2
/dev/vg00/var   /var            ext4    defaults,usrquota,noatime       0 2
/dev/vg00/home  /home           ext4    defaults,usrquota,noatime       0 2
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
none            /proc           proc    defaults        0 0
/root/images/tmpfile.bin       /tmp    ext4    loop,rw,noexec,nosuid 0 0
/tmp            /var/tmp        none    rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,bind 0 0
```

Files that are written to `/tmp` occupy space on the root (`/`) instead of `/var/tmp`: why is that?

*I'm happy to post anything else that might help to answer the question. Thanks.*

Comment: Did you put that loop mount in there?

Comment: @wurtel No I didn't, but I'ma take it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You performed your bind mount backwards. Unmount it, swap the two paths in your fstab, and then mount again.